# Sub-second sampling of a XTS object

Tags: r, xts

I have a XTS object with millisecond time-stamps, the differences between indexes are irregular. Is there an easy way of reducing this time-series to 50ms samples, or 1 second samples for that matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in essence the approach is to

- create a regular time grid for which you can `seq(startPOSIXt, endPOSIXt, by=fracsec)` which can be a `double`, eg 0.1 for 100ms
  as an "empty" `xts` (or `NA` valued xts)
- merge it with your irregularly sampled observations which will now form
  a larger data set following the merge with the regular time grid
- apply `na.locf()` to your data
- and then subset from the enlarged set at the regular time points

and *presto!* you have the most-recent observations at the time points you called for.

Comment: I'm just a little unclear on the last point "and the subset from the enlarged set at the regular time", could you expand a little please?

Comment: Merge creates a larger set with a mix of regular and irregular time stamps.  `na.locf()` "fills holes" by carrying forward. The fourth step subsets essentially from the original data, carried forward to the grid points (which had `NA`) to a _smaller_ data set at just the regular grid time points.

Comment: So I subset the larger set using the original data?

Comment: Indexing: `finalData <- mergedData[ regularGrid, ]`

Comment: No worries. I myself needed this once or twice too and got help :)